# Git server allowing remote repository creation

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to setup a git server so that users may be able to create new repositories remotely? I'm thinking of a sort of bare bones, DIY Github work-alike, without fork & pull request capabilities.

Comment: Could you talk more about what you intend to do with this? Why "bare bones"? Why no fork & pull request?

Comment: This is just wishful thinking right now. I have a few Mercurial repositories served from Apache and I know how to setup something similar for git. I was just wondering if I could do it so as not to be involved when my users need to create new repositories.

Comment: in that case you're probably better off with something like Self-Hosted GitLab that provides users with the features they've come to expect. Or eschew all maintenance and go with a fully hosted solution. You do less work, your users get more features.

Answer (score 0):

There's any number of stand-alone Github-like servers. [Self-Hosted GitLab Libre](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-hosted) is free and featureful.

If you want to go crazy bare bones, all your users need is ssh access to a directory on a server. The normal `user@host:path/repo.git` uses ssh. You can read up on this in [Chapter 4 of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Comment: git also comes packaged with a (very) basic server of its own, see [git-daemon](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon)